Maybe you hadn't noticed

Context: At a party, 2 women are having a conversation
What is the difference:
(1) Maybe you hadn't noticed...
(2) Maybe you didn't notice

"2 women are having a conversation." As a British English speaker, I would find (1) (without the typo) idiomatic and (2) not.

"Haven't noticed" would probably be the most idiomatic to my American ears, but "hadn't" is fine as well.

As I see not noticing someone is a past action, we should use simple past instead of past perfect.

The difference can be one of educational level. In the US, a signficant chunk of the population doesn't use the past perfect, and they would say Maybe you didn't notice... to suggest, politely, that something is amiss and you are acting as though everything is normal.  Maybe you hadn't noticed is the more educated version of didn't notice. The present perfect Maybe you haven't noticed seems more "in your face" to me, even a bit snarky.

Please be careful with your spelling.

The difference is that the women were not having a conversation. They are having one.

The two sentences use different tenses..  What is unclear about the use of tense for you in this example.  Did you create the example yourself or did you actually hear two women talking?

Regarding the comment "noticing someone is past action, we sould use simple past instead of past perfect"...
You are missing some of the nuance with "perhaps you hadn't noticed".
The speaker using the past perfect could be paraphrased: "I have noticed that you have been acting as if nothing is amiss, and perhaps your behavior can be explained by an earlier thing, that you had not noticed that anything was amiss in the first place."
The past perfect suggests the speaker has given the matter some thought, has been watching and thinking about it, thus adding some politeness to the utterance.  Polite reticence has a temporal aspect. Reticence and abruptness are opposites, as it were.
With perhaps you haven't noticed, present perfect, the speaker could be paraphrased as "I notice that you're acting as if nothing is amiss, and perhaps that is because you have not noticed that anything is amiss."
I find the present perfect to be a tad impolite, a bit snarky, or at the very least "off the cuff", abrupt. It is pointing out the most forcefully that the person is not noticing something now.
The simple past falls somewhere in the middle of those two. It is direct yet not impolite.  It, too, offers the other person's not noticing something earlier as explanation for their present behavior.But there's less sense that the speaker has been giving the matter some consideration.

"Maybe you didn't notice, but..." refers to a past event and suggests that the person failed to see it. This is to link the event to a present situation which may be a result of that past event.
For example:

Person 1 : "I'm sure I left my keys here"
Person 2 : "Maybe you didn't notice, but John took them"

"Maybe you hadn't noticed, but..." refers to an existing situation rather than a single event - perhaps a situation that came into being over time. The same inference is there that the person didn't see, but suggests this is responsible for their lack of comprehension rather than for the situation.
For example:

Person 1 : "I don't see why rent is suddenly so expensive"
Person 2 : "Maybe you hadn't noticed but it's been going up slowly for years".


"Maybe you hadn't noticed, but..." refers to an existing situation. Person 2 : "Maybe you haven't noticed but its been going up slowly for years".
You explained of " you hadn't noticed", but the example is "you haven't noticed"

@LE123 [...] but it's been going up slowly for years. Spelling.
